# Easiest way to download HTML page from web?

Tags: c++, http, wxwidgets

I have a web page whose content I'd like to download into a wxString. 
For example, let's say that page is this:

http://www.example.com/mypage.html

And wxString would contain HTML source. In some other languages, say PHP 
for example, I would write something like this:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/mypage.html');
```

I guess it is not a one-liner in wxWidgets, and I have peeked into wxHTTP class, but I wonder if there is some simple wrapper class that does the job with minimal code?

Comment: @fuzzy: Of course not, it's example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running on windows you could use the [Microsoft WinHTTP library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382925(VS.85).aspx).  However, having a quick look at the [wxHTTP](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxhttp.html#wxhttp) documentation, WinHTTP probably isn't any easier.

Have a look at this [straightforward wxHTTP sample code](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxHTTP). It is doing exactly what you are after.

Comment: Good stuff.  Glad that was helpful.

Comment: @milan-babuskov Thanks Milan. I am not sure what that is about either :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out libcurl
A quick google will find it.

Answer (score 0):

You will evidently have to write your own wrapper.

But [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html) has a simpler interface that you may find easier to use, although this does add a new dependency to your program.

Comment: And use wxCurl if you decide to use cURL. It will save you time.